# IonicDeepLinkPlugin doesn't fire deeplink event to JS

Tags: ionic2, ios-universal-links

I'm implementing deep-link in ionic, in Android works fine but in IOS don't send the url to the JS. The plugin is capable of opening the app but the function `handleOpenURL` is never called.

When I click over a link the debugger's log:

```
IonicDeepLinkPlugin: Handle continueUserActivity (internal) 
https://www.example.com
```

My versions are:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any Idea?
Thanks in advance!